# Hyperlinking logo in ArcGIS Web AppBuilder?

Tags: arcgis-web-appbuilder, hyperlink

I would like to insert a hyperlink into my organizations logo, in the upper left corner of my ESRI Web AppBuilder app (see photo). Clicking on it currently opens a link to a blank web page. It is hosted on our web server, rather than ArcGIS Online.

Can anyone point me to the correct file and code snippet to edit it?

[image: Web AppBuilder]

Answer (score 2):

I found the **[ESRI documentation](https://community.esri.com/thread/173894)** to do this.

1. Go to the deployed app on your web server.
2. Under the folder, follow the following directory: “\themes\\widgets\". You will find a "Header" folder or a "Header Controller" folder depending on the theme.
3. Right click on this HTML file. it might look as follows:
4. Notice line 4 - It has an  tag with class: logo.
   [image]
5. To make this a hyperlink, just surround this  tag on left and right with an  tag or an anchor tag as follows:

[image]

Notice my second line now has a href and a target property in it.

The href points to your URL of the web page you would like the logo to point to.

The target property is optional. In absence of this property, if you click on the logo, it changes the web app into the desired web page directly. If you have this property as "_blank", it will open the web page in a new tab.

6. Save the HTML file and then refresh the web app. Your logo should now direct your user to the web page you desire.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the root of your application folder for the file named config.json.  Look for the logo link section, the url is located there.  In  this example the url is http://www.google.com

```
"dataSource":{"dataSources":{},"settings":{}},"logoLink":"http://www.google.com","appItemId":"c2a3807f1f6441c886dcd6778d36de48"}
```